# vsftpd ограничение скорости ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd

Было все хорошо. но сейчас заметил, что скорость через FTP стала резаться, стабильно 500кб/сек 
я файлик 100мб передаю несколько минут)
Где копать? откуда получилось ограничение скорости по фтп?
Работаю через тотал командер. на других фтп все норм. ограничений нет.
на виртуалке стоит ubuntu 14 64 и vsftpd

Comment: ВСЕ вопрос снят! была проблема в тотале!

Comment: проблема в тотале! что случилось? не понятно с ним